# how to avoid getting ^M in file?

Tags: vim

I don't know why it  appears in my file when using vim.
Sometimes not in the vim, but in the output of 'git diff', why?

what command can help me check if file under some dir have '^M' problem, and fix all of them?

Comment: I'm voting to close at the moment as this is not constructed as a question. Could you reword it into a question and then post your solution as an answer?

Comment: How to avoid getting the `^M` in the first place?  Probably don't edit files in other Windows text editors as that's where you likely contracted the ^M virus :)

Comment: Actually, from the title of the question I’m not sure whether the question is about how to avoid the `^M` characters or about how to have Vim automatically remove them… …hmm… maybe I need more coffee…

Comment: `dos2unix` is a handy tool if you have many files with this problem.

Comment: @Nick Indeed. There is a helpful example of its use (although not really in a Vim-specific manner) at [fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF | Luis Toubes](http://toub.es/2012/05/28/fatal-crlf-would-be-replaced-lf).

Comment: "How can I avoid this problem?" --how can you avoid *what* problem?

Comment: This is fundamentally ***not*** a programming problem, it is a very general problem with share text formatted files between OSs.